# How to reuse implemented dependency with its aar files

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin

i have some project with some dependency in my first computer(C1) and i have a computer(C2) that has some problem with internet(its isolated).i want to reuse my downloded libs from my C1 and put it in C2. i don't want to use .jar file. just aar files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to everybody. the solution is:
1. add dependency to your online computer.(gradle will build and cache .aar file in the ".gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\${YOUR.PACKAGE.NAME}\${YOUR LIB NAME}\${YOUR_LIB_VERSION}{HASH_FOLDER}\").

> If you don’t know your package name just take a look at build.gradle(app level). In the dependency block you can find it like:
>   Implemented ‘your.package.name:your lib name:your_lib_version’

2.copy the .aar file.

3.in the offline computer open android studio then in the project view(top left corner) change android to project. then go to app folder and you can see "*libs*" folder.

4.drag and drop the .aar file to libs and click "ok i want modify this file anyway"

5.then go to build.gradle(app level) and paste this code there :

```
allprojects {
  repositories {
   jcenter()
   flatDir {
    dirs 'libs'
   }
  }
}
```

6.put this line in the dependency block in the build.gradle(app level)

```
dependencies {
 compile(name:'your lib name', ext:'aar')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [copy the gradle cache](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-copy-gradle-caches-to-another-offline-machine/23413)

> One way you could do this is to gather all of your dependencies in an
>   archive. For example, something like this should grab everything in
>   all configurations:
>
> ```
> task bundleDependencies(type: Zip) {
>      baseName = 'dependencies'
>      configurations.each { configuration ->
>          if (configuration.canBeResolved) { from configuration }
>      } 
>      destinationDir = file('your/Path') // set path
>   }
> ```
>
> Transfer the archive to the offline machine, extract, and use a
>   flatDir repository (maybe conditionally if you want to use it when
>   offline without adding it each time):
>
> ```
> repositories {
>      if (gradle.startParamter.offline) {
>          flatDir { dirs 'path/to/extracted/dependencies/zip' }
>      } 
> }
> ```

then run on C2 with `--offline` parameter for gradle

You can use either the [Zip](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Zip.html), [Tar](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Tar.html) or [Jar](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.html) tasks to export the dependencies, depending on your liking. See [creating archives](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/working_with_files.html#sec:creating_archives_example)

Also just plain copying of the .gradle directory to the same location (because of absolute paths) from C1 to C2 should work.

Comment: where should i look for .tar file ? @leonardkraemer

Comment: you can set the path with `destinationDir = file('your/Path')`

Comment: make sure to put it into the build.gradle of your module, not in the root one. Otherwise it will not pick up the configurations. (At least that is what made the export work for me)

Comment: how should i run the script in android studio ? @leonardkraemer

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34535011/execute-a-custom-independent-gradle-task-in-android-studio