# Label with dynamically created build number react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, build, version

I'm building an app in React Native. I want to include a  field in the settings screen which displays the build version of the app. This is because I test the app on several devices (5 different ones at the moment). A build label would therefore be useful just to be sure what bundle I'm running. The build label will basically just state the date that the bundle was built. For instance 20181201 (which would be 1st of December 2018). I can quite easily just create a constant, and update the constant manually before building a bundle. However, this relies on me remembering to update that label. It would be nice if this label was automatically generated at the time of build. Any good suggestions as to how I could achieve this in React Native?

Comment: Did you check [react-native-device-info](https://github.com/rebeccahughes/react-native-device-info) library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use a json file that contains information about the build. This json file is then imported and its contents are used to make a footer on the settings page, this allows me to track which build is on which device.

Personally I use Bitrise to make my builds, so in my workflow there I have a step that runs a bash script that updates the json file with specific information. i.e. date and time of build, Bitrise build number etc.

**Alternatively if you don't use a CI suite like Bitrise**

For iOS you could use a `Pre-action` in Xcode and run a script that would update the json file when you create your archive. `Edit schema...` select `Pre-actions` and then add a `Run Script`.

[image: edit scheme]

For Android you could use a custom task as explained in this SO answer [Execute a custom independent gradle task in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34535011/execute-a-custom-independent-gradle-task-in-android-studio)

Comment: I build my bundles using the terminal, so including a bash script that changes the build number in a json file based on the date, prior to the build command, is a great solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you write the build number you want in:

**Android** - app/build.gradle versionCode property

**iOS** - ios/[APP_NAME]/info.plist CFBundleVersion property

You can use [react-native-device-info](https://github.com/rebeccahughes/react-native-device-info).

Check out getBuildNumber method.

Comment: This was also a great answer! Thanks for the help.

Comment: Super, super easy answer.  AND... the Device info provides so much more information.  Thanks!  :-)