# how to check the external dependency size in android studio

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies

How can I check the exact size of the dependency that I installed in android studio, is there any website to check the size..?
I want to know the size of `implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.X.X'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a task to sum the size of all the files in a configuration.  Then add the dependency or dependencies that you want to check to that configuration. (In addition to the `implementation` configuration or whatever other configuration it is that they are needed for.)

```
configurations {
   justForSize
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.X.X'
    justForSize 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.X.X'
}

tasks.register('dependencySize') {
    doLast {
        def depLength = 0L
        configurations.justForSize.forEach {
            println "${it} is ${it.length()} bytes"
            depLength += it.length()
        }
        println "Total size of justForSize configuration is ${depLength}"
   }
}
```

Then just run that task:

```
gradle dependencySize
```

Comment: I appreciate your response, however I'm a little unsure on where to execute the command `gradle dependencySize`.

Comment: @NISHANTHDURAI Run it in your project folder.  Assuming you have gradle installed outside of your IDE.  If the project was configured to use the gradle wrapper you would use ```gradlew dependencySize```.  I don't use Android Studio, but check this answer for running arbitrary tasks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34535011/execute-a-custom-independent-gradle-task-in-android-studio